# How can I calculate rank based on highest Score and lowest Minutes in MySql Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Table Structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user_result` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ResultId`int(11),
   `PaperId` int(11) ,
   `Title` varchar(45),
   `TotalQuestions` int(11) ,
   `Attempt` int(11) ,
   `Correct` int(11) ,
   `Wrong` int(11) ,
   `Score` int(45) ,
   `Minutes` int(11) ,
   `TimeSt` varchar(45) ,
   `UserEmail` varchar(45) ,
   `UserName` varchar(45) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));
```

I tried following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    id,
    PaperId,
    Title,
    Score,
    Minutes,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM
            tbl_user_result 
        WHERE
            Score > x.Score AND Minutes > x.Minutes) AS Rank
FROM
    `tbl_user_result` as x
```

Comment: What is wrong? Please be more specific.

Comment: my try give wrong output. if i modify Where clause  to "Score > x.Score " this gives result based on only score

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use variables:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
      from tbl_user_result r cross join (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by score desc, minutes asc
     ) r;
```

This works if you have no duplicates.

I think the following is the version of your query that you want:

```
SELECT id, PaperId, Title, Score, Minutes,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM tbl_user_result r2
        WHERE r2.Score > r.Score OR
              (r2.Score = r.Score AND r2.Minutes < r.Minutes)
       ) AS Rank
FROM  tbl_user_result r;
```

Comment: showing wrong syntax :  syntax to use near 'AS Rank FROM tbl_user_result r'

Comment: Hey just on bracket is missing. works grate, thank you very much "expert"